# PHP function for comparing two variable?

Tags: php

Is there any PHP function for comparing two string variable with the third parameter are comparison operators and return boolean.

Example:

```
$string1 = "Foo";
$string2 = "Bar";
$result = php_function_for_comparing($string1, $string2, "=="); //return boolean
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comparing them directly is to easy? `$result = ($string1 === $string2)`. What is the reason for such a function?

Comment: I assume he's looking to be able to pass a closure as the third argument

Comment: No, there is no such a function in PHP. It is something you need to code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question i've created a simple function without using php eval().

```
function variable_comparison($condition = "==", $var1, $var2 = false){
    if($condition == "is_empty")
        return empty($var1);
    else if($condition == "is_filled")
        return !empty($var1);
    else if($condition == "==")
        return $var1 == $var2;
    else if($condition == "!=")
        return $var1 != $var2;
    else if($condition == ">")
        return $var1 > $var2;
    else if($condition == "<")
        return $var1 < $var2;
    else if($condition == ">=")
        return $var1 >= $var2;
    else if($condition == "<=")
        return $var1 <= $var2;
    else if($condition == "in_array")
        return in_array($var1, $var2);
    else if($condition == "contains")
        return strpos($var1, $var2);
    else if($condition == "starts_with")
        return substr($var1, 0, strlen($var2)) === $var2;
    else if($condition == "ends_width"){
        $length = strlen($var2);
        return !$length || substr($var1, - $length) === $var2;
    }       
}
```

This function is very useful when you are writing a basic conditional logic and save it as a sting.

Example conditional logic string:

```
$string_logic = "{if post_[foo]<!=>post_[bar]?post_[bar]:Defalut Value Here!}";
```

Same result as:

```
echo ($_POST["foo"] != $_POST["bar"]) ? $_POST["bar"] : "Default Value Here!";
```

But of course you need to create a recursive algorithm to evaluate the string and convert it into PHP readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* use the eval function - but be aware, that `eval` executes ANY php code passed to it. So you have to properly validate ANY input given to that method!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
$operator1 = "==";
$operator2 = "!=";

$string1 = "'foo'"; //quote them for evaluation, or you receive syntax errors
$string2 = "'bar'"; //quote them for evaluation, or you receive syntax errors

if (eval("return ".$string1 . $operator1 . $string2.";")){
   echo "Equal!";
}

if (eval("return ".$string1 . $operator2 . $string2.";")){
   echo "Different!";
}
```

or without quoting the values prior:

```
$operator1 = "==";
$operator2 = "!=";

$string1 = "foo"; 
$string2 = "bar";

//this passes the strings $string1 and $string2 - which will THEN 
//be evaluated to the values.
if (eval('return $string1' . $operator1 . '$string2;')){ 
   echo "Equal!";
}

if (eval('return $string1' . $operator2 . '$string2;')){
   echo "Different!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I really disagree of using eval(). It will work but apart from the security concerns it is also difficult to sanitize the string parameter for eval.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah many and you can be clever with them to use them as a boolean

```
//Calculate the percentage of similarities
similar_text ($first , $second, $percent )

levenshtein($str1, $str2) //Calculate Levenshtein distance between two strings

soundex($str) //Calculate the soundex key of a string
```

Comment: I read the question. You are asking if there is a php function which compares two strings and then return a Boolean true or false, Right?

Comment: Nope... Try again. Read all the words. Process all the words, then attempt an answer

Comment: I need the third argument to be comparison operator like "==, <=, >=, >, <, !=" and return Boolean value. similar_text() calculate the similarity only.

Comment: @EdwardManda Did you get it now?

Comment: yeah, I get what you are asking. There is no built in php function to do that. You have to create one yourself.